# for loop in thread_create terminates, does not print anything

Tags: c

A for loop in thread_create terminates and does not print anything.
When I debug in gdb, watch new thread terminate immediately.
I don't know why?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* myturn(void * arg){
    for(int j; ; j++){
         sleep(3);
        fprintf(stderr, "my turn\n");
        printf("my turn\n");
        //pthread_exit(0);
    }
    sleep(3);
    return NULL;
}

int yourturn(){
    for(int i; i<3; i++){
        sleep(2);
        printf("your turn\n");
    }
}

int main(int arg, char * argv[]){
    pthread_t new_thread;
    pthread_create(&new_thread, NULL, myturn, NULL);
    // myturn();
    yourturn();
    pthread_join(new_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you aren't initialising your for loop variables so your program has undefined behaviour

Comment: does it "work" without threads?

Comment: This is just C code, so if you're actually using C++ please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I modified you code a little and its working:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void* myturn(void * arg){
    
    int j = 0;
    for(j=0; j<10; j++){
         sleep(1);
        fprintf(stderr, "my turn\n");
        printf("my turn\n");
        //pthread_exit(0);
         
    }
    sleep(1);
    return NULL;
}

int yourturn(){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<30; i++){
        sleep(2);
        printf("your turn\n");
    }

}

int main(int arg, char * argv[]){
    pthread_t new_thread;
    pthread_create(&new_thread, NULL, myturn, NULL);
    // myturn();
    yourturn();
    pthread_join(new_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The problems I found were that you can't initialize a variable in the loop and you have to describe more itens in the loop.

Errors:

- ```
   for(int j; ; j++){
  ```
- ```
   for(int i; i<3; i++){
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try after initializing the loop variables i and j to zero or something.